# Crontab expression for run once between time range that crosses midnight

Tags: crontab

Is it possible to come up with a cron expression that runs every five minutes between 12th October 2015 19:00 and 13th October 2015 07:00?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Minute   Hour   Day of Month       Month          Day of Week        Command    
# (0-59)  (0-23)     (1-31)    (1-12 or Jan-Dec)  (0-6 or Sun-Sat)
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 19,20,21,22,23 12 10 * command
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 13 10 * command
0 7 13 10 * command
```

Comment: Is your 3rd entry intended?

Comment: Yes; the last entry runs at 07:00 on October 13th (but not at 07:05).

Comment: AH...gotcha... =]

Answer (score 0):

well not ONE, but i think most close:

```
*/5 19-23 12 10 * test $(date +%Y) -eq 2015 && /runme.sh
*/5 0-6   13 10 * test $(date +%Y) -eq 2015 && /runme.sh
0   7     13 10 * test $(date +%Y) -eq 2015 && /runme.sh
```

My advice so is to place date check into your script (runme.sh) and simply put to crontab:

```
*/5 * 12-13 10 * /runme.sh
```

and start runme.sh like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
test $(date +%Y) -eq 2015 || exit 0
test $(date %d%H%M) -ge 121900 || exit 0
test $(date %d%H%M) -le 130700 || exit 0
```